# Paypal Smart Buttons don't work in email due to the Javascript needed. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html, email, paypal

I followed [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/) to add the PayPal Smart Buttons to an HTML file, which I then tried to just copy to an email. However, the buttons won't appear - I'm sure it's because of the JavaScript not being run by the email reader.

My desired outcome is to email a client requesting payment and have them just click a button that will bring them through the transaction (PayPal Smart Buttons also have the ability to pay via Debit or Credit card). As I run a business I want it to look professional hence why I did the email with HTML/CSS.

So what are some workarounds or suggestions for how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At https://www.paypal.com/buttons , if you are logged in, you can create a "Share on Social" button. This link will work in an email.

If you create any other non-Smart button and do not change any settings in the "Customize" box (i.e. do NOT add a dropdown menu or text field), after generating the button code you will also have an "E-mail" tab with a link.

---

Since you are sending emails to clients requesting payment, you might want to just send them a PayPal invoice, via https://www.paypal.com/invoice/create

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Paypal buttons are great. However, in the end you have code to use for web or email. The web option contains <form> tags so it's not the way to go as it's the same result as before. The email option is just a hyperlink for posting in an email. As I wrote it in HTML and CSS it doesn't work either. I tried creating a button with a Paypal image that links to the hyperlink provided, but it seems dishonest and it actually didn't work. I was looking at invoices but it wasn't exactly how I wanted to send the email to the customer. I'd prefer it all in one created email.

Comment: I understand it gets tricky with PayPal and there are certain perimeters you must follow for security. I was looking into their invoice system already and if I can't do it the way I'm trying, I can reword the email with instructions that an invoice email will follow.

Comment: Taking one of the hyperlinks and making a button image point to that link is the best you can do in your own emails.  PayPal invoices are useful in that they let you keep track of what has/hasn't been paid right within your PayPal account.